# AngularJs. Render table with ng repeat and ng switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I'm trying render table with two columns using `angularjs` directives.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages" >
    <td ng-switch-on="message.network" ng-switch when="twitter" ng-controller="TweetController">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-checked="{{message.isPublished}}" data-id="{{message.socialId}}" ng-click="publishMessage($event)" />
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="{{message.authorPicture}}" />
        </span>
        <span>{{message.createdAt}}</span>
        <span>{{message.network}}</span>
        <span>{{message.text}}</span>
    </td>
    <td ng-switch-on="message.network" ng-switch when="facebook" ng-controller="FacebookController">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-checked="{{message.isPublished}}" data-id="{{message.socialId}}" data-createdAt="{{message.createdAt}}" ng-click="publishMessage($event)" />
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="{{message.authorPicture}}" />
        </span>
        <span>{{message.createdAt}}</span>
        <span>{{message.network}}</span>
        <span>{{message.text}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There are should be 2 columns - in first should be twitter messages, in second should be facebook posts. But in my case the same message renders in both columns(Like this http://puu.sh/5oHT7.png). What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I dont think you need `ngSwitch` here. To keep things simple you could just restructure `$scope.messages` so that each of its item contains data from both the networks.

Comment: Could you share the contents of `$scope.messages`?

Comment: Of course))
http://pastebin.com/SSMiy6kL

Comment: Can you post `messages` object

Comment: Maxim, pastebin.com/SSMiy6kL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep things simple just restructure the model:

```
$scope.messages = [
    [
        {
            "network": "twitter",
            ...
        },
        {
            "network": "facebook",
            ...
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "network": "twitter",
            ...
        },
        {
            "network": "facebook",
            ...
        }
    ]       
]
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="message in messages" >
        <td ng-repeat="msg in message">
            <div ng-if="msg.network == 'twitter'">
                <div ng-controller="TweetController">
                    ...
                    <span>{{msg.createdAt}}</span>
                    <span>{{msg.network}}</span>
                    <span>{{msg.text}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="msg.network == 'facebook'">
                <div ng-controller="FacebookController">
                    ...
                    <span>{{msg.createdAt}}</span>
                    <span>{{msg.network}}</span>
                    <span>{{msg.text}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But for facebbok i use FacebookController, for twitter - TwitterController. How i determinate in what case use twitter controller, and in what - facebook controller?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is delightfully! :-)

Comment: @SvetlanaIvanova No problem. Unless you are doing something considerably different with both the views you should have a single controller `MessagesController`. Just a suggestion. See what best suits your needs :)

Comment: i faced with new problem :-)
http://puu.sh/5oLCe.png
Now messages repeats in 1 column) ng-if the root of problem(

Comment: Just make sure if the problem is in `$scope.messages` itself.

Comment: @SvetlanaIvanova Oh! `ngIf` is available only in newer Angular versions 1.5 and above.

Comment: Yeah. Like I already said version 1.5 or above. Not the versions before. You should not have any difficulties using `ngIf`, if you're using V 1.2.1.

Comment: I'm tryin with angular 1.1.5 and everything ok! Merci )